# How to create a member group admin?

Tags: members, extension, admin, member-management, groups

What i try to achive is to have the following user structure:

Member Group 1: Group Admin, User 1, User 2,...
Member Group 2: Group Admin, User 1, User 2,...
Member Group 3 ...
...

I want the group admin to be able to add/remove/edit members only within his group.

I know this will not be possible with bare EE install, but I hope that with some ad-ons and a bit of tinkering will be doable. I've looked on the devot:ee website, but most of the plugins are quite cryptic in description and I would love someone would point me in the right direction.

So given the problem above, how would you approach the solution. Which plugins to use? Is it even possible without writing custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

Even if an existing addon can do this, what you want seems so specialised to me that you may be better off with a module/extensions combination. I think you would need a module to hold the group/member combinations. And I think you will need more than one extension. The extensions would use the group/member combinations to control who the logged-in admin can register, edit and delete.

For security, access to the module CP would have to be limited, possibly to superadmins, otherwise your intention to limit admins to the groups they can manage would be insecure.

Whichever way you look at this, there is quite a bit of coding required, because registration, deletion and editing all have different extension hooks that would have to be brought into play, and assigning/unassigning multiple users to the group/member combinations could be a challenge on a site with many members.

EDIT
Here's another issue - there would have to be a way to prevent other admins from re-assigning members to their own groups.

Looks like a minefield to me.